# how to animate matplotlib function optimization?

Tags: python, animation, optimization, scipy

I am trying to make something similar to Matlab function optimization animation. There is a package in Matlab which allows animation of optimization functions.

I don't want to call `anim.FuncAnimation` because my optimization function will be called automatically via `scipy.minimize`

In the argument to `scipy.minimize` the optimization function should do the animation for instance...

```
lines.set_data(x,y)
```

Here x and y will be from the optimization function. Obviously this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact you don't know in advance how many function call it is going to be there before the target function is minimized, therefore it may make more sense to retrieve all the optimize vectors and plot them afterwards.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import scipy.optimize as si
import scipy.optimize as so

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-0.5, 3.5), ylim=(-10, 100))
line, = ax.plot([], [], 'o')

def F(x):
        return (x**3-x**2-9.)**2

#get the optimize progress
res_x = []
so.fmin(F, -9, callback=res_x.append)
res_x = np.array(res_x).ravel()
res_y = F(res_x)

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    line.set_data(res_x[i], res_y[i])
    return line,

ax.plot(np.linspace(0,10,100), F(np.linspace(0,10,100)), 'g')
#frames is the length of res_x
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=len(res_x), interval=200, blit=True)
```

[image]