# Persistent drawings with matplotlib animations

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am trying to implement [Alec Radford's visualizations of gradient descents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZOUf.jpg) in Python with matplotlib animation. I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25422073/how-to-animate-matplotlib-function-optimization), which is a good start and I have been playing around a bit with the code.

However I am wondering how to animate persistent lines.
(For example the ones that show the different path taken by the algorithm for different gradient descent in Alec's visualizations).

Maybe a link to the code Alec used is available it certainly looks like it was also done in matplotlib...

Comment: See http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/animate_decay.html

Comment: Thanks ! I will look into it today !

Comment: @tcaswell yes that seems to be exactly what I was looking for ! I will let you answer then !